# JPA many-to-many association

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I am creating a very simple sample application to understand the behavior of jpa many-to-many association.

As per my understanding, after execution of Main.java , the application should create only 3 entries in Subject table; each for "Software Engineering" , "Distributed System" and "Business Analysis and Optimization" with its own ID as shown in the image below.

[image]

But actually it's creating 4 entries in Subject Table having one duplicate entries for subject "Software Engineering" as it is being taught in both the "CSE" and "IT" as shown in the image below.

[image]

Is it a correct behavior. If not how can i make only 3 entries in Subject table by running Main.java

**Below are my source code.**

**MySQL DB Script**

```
CREATE DATABASE jpa;

USE jpa;

CREATE TABLE BRANCH (
  BRANCH_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  BRANCH_SHORT_NAME varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  BRANCH_NAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BRANCH_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE Subject (
  SUBJECT_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  SUBJECT_NAME varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  SUBJECT_DESC varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (SUBJECT_ID)
);


CREATE TABLE BRANCH_SUBJECT (
  BRANCH_ID int NOT NULL,
  SUBJECT_ID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BRANCH_ID,SUBJECT_ID),
  KEY SUBJECT_ID_FK_idx (SUBJECT_ID),
  CONSTRAINT BRANCH_SUB_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (BRANCH_ID) REFERENCES BRANCH (BRANCH_ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT SUBJECT_SUB_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (SUBJECT_ID) REFERENCES Subject (SUBJECT_ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);


COMMIT;
```

**pom.xml dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.24</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Entity Classes**

**Branch.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Branch implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "BRANCH_ID")
    private int branchId;

    @Column(name = "BRANCH_NAME")
    private String branchName;

    @Column(name = "BRANCH_SHORT_NAME")
    private String branchShortName;

    private String description;

    //Uni-directional many-to-many association to Subject
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "BRANCH_SUBJECT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BRANCH_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID"))
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    public void addSubject(Subject subject) {
        this.subjects.add(subject);
    }
}
```

**Subject.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Subject implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID")
    private int subjectId;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_DESC")
    private String subjectDesc;

    @Column(name = "SUBJECT_NAME")
    private String subjectName;

}
```

**Main.java**

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        EntityTransaction transaction = null;

        try {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-persistence-unit");
            entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
            transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();

            Branch branch1 = getBranch1();//CSE Branch in Engineering
            Branch branch2 = getBranch2();//IT Branch in Engineering
            branch1.setSubjects(new HashSet<>());
            branch1.addSubject(getSubject1());//Software Engineering
            branch1.addSubject(getSubject2());//Distributed System
            branch2.setSubjects(new HashSet<>());
            branch2.addSubject(getSubject1());//Software Engineering
            branch2.addSubject(getSubject3());//Business Analysis and Optimization

            entityManager.persist(branch1);
            entityManager.persist(branch2);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            entityManager.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }

    private static Subject getSubject1() {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setSubjectName("Software Engineering");
        subject.setSubjectDesc("Apply key aspects of software engineering processes for the development of a complex software system");

        return subject;
    }

    private static Subject getSubject2() {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setSubjectName("Distributed System");
        subject.setSubjectDesc("Explore recent advances in distributed computing systems");

        return subject;
    }

    private static Subject getSubject3() {
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.setSubjectName("Business Analysis and Optimization");
        subject.setSubjectDesc("understand the Internal and external factors that impact the business strategy");

        return subject;
    }

    private static Branch getBranch1() {
        Branch branch = new Branch();
        branch.setBranchName("Computer Science and Engineering");
        branch.setBranchShortName("CSE");
        branch.setDescription("CSE department offers courses under ambitious curricula in computer science and computer engineering..");

        return branch;
    }

    private static Branch getBranch2() {
        Branch branch = new Branch();
        branch.setBranchName("Information Technology");
        branch.setBranchShortName("IT");
        branch.setDescription("IT is the business side of computers - usually dealing with databases, business, and accounting");

        return branch;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are creating two distinct entity objects without a primary key value and you setup persist cascading.

You can solve this by referring to only a single subject1 object in both `subjects` collections of the branches.